# CSS Animation: fade out and translate text and fade back in but with larger font size

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to create an animation with CSS so that a given element (in the example, an h2 tag) when hovered moves a bit and fades out, and come back a few moments later fading in with a larger font-size.

Ideally:

- This would occur on hover and the inverse when no longer hovering.
- Without specifying the initial font size (in the example 2rem).

I've been trying some solutions with animations but so far nothing close to what I'm looking for.

Thanks

Edit: added short animation of what I was looking for (line is there for geometric reference of the text's position):

[image]

Edit2: the GIF if looping, but the text is supposed to remain large while the container element is hovered.

```css
:root {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  padding: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

h2 {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 2rem;
}

:root:hover h2 {
  font-size: 5rem;
  animation: text 1s forwards ease-out;
}

@keyframes text {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(-30px);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
  }
}
```

```html
  <h2>TEXT</<h2>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for providing a snippet. Not sure this is what you opted for. I added a flex container to center the text, but this is optional.

```css
:root {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  padding: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

h2 {
  font-family: Arial;
}

:root:hover h2 {
  animation: text 1s forwards ease-out;
}

@keyframes text {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0px);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  25% {
    transform: translateY(-30px);
    opacity: 0;
    font-size: 1rem;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  75% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  100% {
    font-size: 5rem;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div style="height: 150px; display:flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center;">
<h2>TEXT</h2>
</div>
```

UPDATE: Attempting doing the gif animation

```css
:root {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  padding: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

h2 {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 2em;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  line-height: 1;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%
}

:root:hover h2 {
  animation: text 1s forwards ease-out;
}

@keyframes text {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0px);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  25% {
    transform: translateY(+50px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0;
    font-size: 2em;
  }
  75% {
    opacity: 0;
    font-size: 5em;
    transform: translateY(+50px);
  }
  100% {
    font-size: 5rem;
    transform: translateY(0px);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div style="height: 100px; position: relative; border: 1px solid red;">
  <h2>TEXT</h2>
</div>
<hr>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. It's mostly what you have there, although it should scale when not visible and stay in the sample baseline. I've added an animation of what I was looking for in the OP. Thanks!

Comment: The updated suggestion is on point. Thank you very much. One detail though, you used both `em` and `rem` in the text sizing and I had to set all to the same units in order to get it to run properly in my use case. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

The root element confuses me. Nevertheless, you can add a font-size and oppacity 0 at 50 percent. The element will return to the original place afterwards. The margin-top keeps the element with the bigger font size in place. Not sure if this is the ideal solution.

Maybe just personal preference. I have changed the animation to ease-in-out, see https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp

```css
:root {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  text-align: center;
}

h2 {
  font-family: Arial;
  padding: 0px;
}

:root:hover h2 {
  animation: text 3s forwards ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes text {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0;
    font-size: 2rem;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    margin-top: 1.5rem;
    font-size: 3.5rem;
  }
}
```

```html
  <h2>TEXT</<h2>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer but it's far from what I was looking for. I've added some info to the OP